# Program prints 0 as result of multiplication of two positive integers obtained via scanf("%f")

Tags: c, scanf

My Code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int l, b, a;
    printf("Enter the length of the rectangle: ");
    scanf("%f", &l);

    printf("Enter the breadth of the rectangle: ");
    scanf("%f", &b);

    printf("Area of rectangle is %f", l * b);
    return 0;
}
```

When I give any input it doesn't show me its product, but `0.000000` instead: [image]

As I gave input 2 and 3, it should print `Area of rectangle is 6`

Comment: Please read the [scanf](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html) and [printf](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html) manuals. `%f` is not for integers. The manual will tell you what it should be instead.

Comment: You're mismatching the conversion specifier (the `"%f"`) and the variable type (type `int`). scanf wants `"%d"` for `int`s; `"%f"` for `float`s and, **better** if you want to use floating-point, `"%lf"` for `double`s

Comment: And please turn on all warnings for your compiler, it should have told you already

Comment: The `%f` format expects a pointer to `float`; you are passing a pointer to `int`.  Make the format match the variable type or vice versa.

Comment: @Mat How to turn on warnings?

Comment: Thanks Everyone for solving my problem.

Comment: If you are learning C, you should avoid scanf: http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html

Comment: @Mat I had turned on Intellisense but don't know how to turn on warnings?

Comment: @WilliamPursell Then what should we use instead of scanf?

Comment: @AdityaSoni There are many options, and several are outlined on the page I provided.  `fgetc`, `fgets`, etc.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Thanks for your suggestion, but would you like to give a illustration of using ```fgetc``` and ```fgets```.

Comment: You'll need to read the first chapter of a beginner level C programming book before you start coding. Format specifiers to printf/scanf are typically mentioned in that first chapter.

Comment: @Lundin I am learning ```c``` from ```codewithharry``` on youtube. He is teaching from the very beginning.

Comment: Not very successfully, it would seem. Any random person can post a youtube video. But publishers almost only let experts write C books. Or as someone wisely said, "He who searches for wisdom on youtube is a-..."

Comment: @Lundin Then which book should I read? As I learnt python and flask from him. I started learning ```c``` from him.

Comment: Please anyone tell me why my question is downvoted?

Comment: I don't know which books there are that's actually newbie-friendly. [Modern C/Gustedt](https://gustedt.gitlabpages.inria.fr/modern-c/) is probably the most up to date one (and free as pdf), though I suspect it might be a bit too advanced to keep up with for someone just learning the language.

Comment: As for down votes (I didn't down vote, but close vote), likely lack of research. This kind of question with a trivial mismatch of format specifiers has already been asked thousands of times before on SO.

Comment: Thanks @Lundin I will start learning from it.

Comment: @AdityaSoni You can at least use it for reference when you need to look something up.

Comment: I thought that I installed compiler the wrong way and searching for that.

Comment: I can recommend https://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/cclass.html (although I'm admittedly biased).

Comment: Using `scanf` to get numbers into your programs is not the end of the world, and is fine for, say, your first three weeks of C programming.  You've got a lot to learn at first, and a few other things might come first.  Soon enough, though, you'll do yourself a big favor by weaning yourself off of `scanf` and abandoning it forever.  See [What can I use for input conversion instead of scanf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58403537)

Comment: Regarding scanf, I'd just say that learning console input/output with `stdio.h` is largely obsolete practice. Console I/O is only used in niche system level programming nowadays, so don't invest a lot of time and energy into learning all the dirty details of it. Most desktop programs/engines etc have a GUI and C is just a back-end for performance-critical or hardware-related programming. So stdio.h is just one lib among many that you could learn after learning the language itself, I regard it as a quick & dirty debug library for testing, not something to use in production code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`%f` expects its corresponding argument to have type `float` and you are passing `int` to it, so changing it to `%d` would fix the issue, as `%d` expects its corresponding argument to have type int.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
 
int main() {
   int length, breadth, area;
 
   printf("\nEnter the Length of Rectangle: ");
   scanf("%d", &length);
 
   printf("\nEnter the Breadth of Rectangle: ");
   scanf("%d", &breadth);
 
   area = length * breadth;
   printf("\nArea of Rectangle: %d\n", area);
 
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: ```getch()``` is for? Actually, I started learning today and stuck in error.

Comment: This code exhibits undefined behavior on certain inputs.  Code provided as an example for beginners should not do this.  You *must* check the value returned by scanf.  Always.

Comment: Actually in old turbo c compilers the output screen won't stay so getch() method pauses the Output Console until a key is pressed

Comment: @Kundan Yes, if I run file outside the vscode it closes as I it reaches EOF

Comment: @WilliamPursell Understood your point, but I was fixing the issue which was there in the code which was mentioned in the question.

Comment: @AdityaSoni I hope you understood the points and the answer helped you.

Comment: @AdityaSoni Forget that you ever saw conio.h and getch. It's from an ancient non-standard library used for MS DOS programming that everyone in the world except a certain large country in central Asia stopped using 20 years ago.

Comment: @Lundin Thanks for your suggestions. As I use VS Code, I never need to pause file at last.

Comment: @AdityaSoni yeah, while using new compilers, you don't have to use that.